# Limit user uploads 4 at a time

Tags: php, image, upload, fine-uploader

I am using fineuploader php server code to handle image uploads.

I have searched web and so far couldn't find what I want.

**I want to allow user upload maximum 4 images at a time. (no multiple select allowed, user need to select one by one image)**

I can solve it with client side, but what about server side? How do I detect if more than 4?

Example:
FB allows select multiple images up to few hundreds. imagine FB only allow maximum 4 images

Any solution to this?

**UPDATE**
I need 4 max for one function. others function need more than 4. I don't think it is good idea to set php.ini

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of the other answers here assume that multiple files are sent with a single request.  That is not true with Fine Uploader.  Each file is sent in a separate request.

As you mentioned, Fine Uploader already handles this client-side with the [`validation.itemLimit` option](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/options.html#validation-option).  If you want to add a server-side check as well, you'll need to ensure some user data, such as an ID, is passed with each request.  This way, you can limit a specific user to a set number of files.  You should already have some sort of a cookie set that allows your server to match a request to a specific user.  This cookie will be passed, by default, with each request.

Comment: You could also use a session variable that is incremented on each upload. You would also have to reset it after a time to allow him to upload again... If you have a login and want this counter to be permanent, you could also store this counter in your DB for each user.
A cookie value could be faked and is not safe (which might not be important here though).

Answer (score 0):

PHP Count - [www.php.net/count‎](http://www.php.net/count%E2%80%8E)

E.g.

```
if(count($_FILES) > 4) { /*Throw error*/ }
```

Comment: it return 1 always. why is that?

Comment: ... because this answer is not correct.  Not sure why so many people upvoted it.  This will only check the number of files sent in a single request.  Fine Uploader only sends one file per request.